# Basic conditional probability problem on cats and dogs.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Suppose $36\%$ of families own a dog, $30\%$ of families own a cat, and $22\%$
> of the families that have a dog also have a cat. A family is chosen at random and found to
> have a cat. What is the probability they also own a dog?

D: Family owns a dog.

C: Family owns a cat.

"$22\%$ of the families that have a dog also have a cat" - **why this is not $D \cap C$** ?

Comment: $P(C|D)=P(D \cap C)/P(D) \ne P(D \cap C)$

Comment: Re-stating in words, the comment of @JeanMarie , the probability of a family having a cat+dog is different from the probability of a family having a cat+dog, **given** that the family has a cat.

Comment: If there were $100,000$ families, then $36,000$ would own a dog and $7,920$ of those would own a cat, so the number owning a dog and a cat is not $22\%$ of $100,000$.  To answer the underlying question, note that $30,000$ would own a cat

Answer (score -1):

"$22\%$ of *the families that have a dog* also have a cat"

This is a fraction of *the families that have a dog*, rather than of *all the families*.

Thus it is a conditional probability, $\mathsf P(C\mid D)$, rather than the conjunct probability, $\mathsf P(C\cap D)$.

Hence, you seek the fraction of *families that have a cat* which also have a dog. $\mathsf P(D\mid C)$.

And you should know that by the definition of conditional probability $$\mathsf P(C\cap D)=\mathsf P(D)~\mathsf P(C\mid D)~=~\mathsf P(C)~\mathsf P(D\mid C)$$

Answer (score -1):

In the question the phrase that the family is selected at random is found to have a cat implies that our sample space is now reduced to those containing cats as sample space N(C),as the event has already occured and we have cat in our hand  and now probability that in these selected families(having cats) the family that also contains dog is P(D when C has been found out)=N(C int D) / N(C) now divide num and den by total sample space this results in conditional probability expression I have just elaborated that if u do P(C int D) then you are not considering the fact that the selected family is already having cat
Hope that it helps!
Please vote if you like the answer.
int:- intersection

Comment: The lack of punctuation (to partition your paragraph into sentences) makes this hard to understand. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).